# Of what kind of lvalues can the address not be taken?

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue

In [this conference](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151094464083109&set=vb.9445547199&type=2), Scott Meyers starts by saying "lvalues are generally expressions you can take the address of". I am stressing the word generally: what is an lvalue that you cannot take the address of? (if it exists).

**EDIT**:
Please provide code snippets with your answers, it make things clearer.

Comment: Did you mean **lvalues** in your title??

Comment: yea o.O can’t believe I wrote rvalue

Comment: I didn't get into the complete conference video, but looking at the text around I guess S.M. is really talking about 'rvalues' here. The most relevant thing I found regarding your question seems to be found here: (http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html)

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is hardware specific. In TI DSPs, they've extended C/C++ such that you can have `extern cregister volatile unsigned int AMR;`, where `AMR` referes to a particular hardware register (In this case, the Addressing Mode Register).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think bitfields satisfy your conditions... I believe `f.x` is an lvalue, but you can't take the address of it. Interestingly, you also can't do `auto & x = f.x`.

> **C++11 Section 8.3.1 Part of Paragraph 4:** Since the address of a bit-field (9.6) cannot be taken, a pointer can never point to a bit-field.

```
struct foo {
    int x : 3;
    int y : 3;
    int z : 3;
};

int main() {
    foo f;

    f.x = 3;
}
```

---

*I'm even less sure about this other idea, but the standard says that you are not allowed to **use** the main function. If taking the address of main is using it, then that would also suffice. C++11 3.6.1 Paragraph 5.*

---

*And from a comment I left, I know TI extends their C and C++ compilers such that there is a storage class called `cregister` that you can't take the address of. (Because it refers to a physical register, which doesn't have a concept of an address).*

Comment: Taking something's address qualifies as "ODR-use", so I think you're right about `main`.

Comment: @ildjarn But since `main` isn’t an lvalue anyway, how is that interesting here?

Comment: @Konrad : `main` is a function, and functions are lvalues. I don't see anything in §3.6.1 that says otherwise – what am I missing?

Comment: @ildjarn Functions are lvalues? Oh bother, C++ confuses the hell out of me. You cannot assign to a function. Why is it an lvalue then? Intuitively it shouldn’t be … just because you can take its address? (Well, parochially because §3.10 says so but this is of course not an explanation …)

Answer (score 0):

You can take addresses from named symbols (e.g. vs. temporary instances). That's what's making up an lvalue as far I understood this explanation.